# derivative of a definite integral with base e

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_3^{x^2} e^{t^3} dt$$

I can sorta figure out how to solve problems like this, if it was an indefinite integral...

Comment: It is indefinite integral with limits. All you have to do is calculate the indefinite integral and the see what the function takes value at upper limit and what the function takes value at lower limit. Then subtract lower limit value from upper limit value.

Comment: It's actually helpful to think of the definition of derivative in problems like this.

Comment: It works like this. Suppose $\int f(x)=F(x)$ then $\int_a^b f(x)=F(b)-F(a)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derivative with respect to the integration limit returns the integrand, evaluated at the limit.

$$\frac{d}{dz}\int_3^{z}e^{t^3}dt=e^{z^3}$$
Because $z=x^2$ and you take the derivative with respect to $x$, you need the chain rule.

$$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d}{dz}$$
so now you have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_3^{x^2}e^{t^3}dt=\left(\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}\right)e^{x^6}=2xe^{x^6}$$

The derivative with respect to the lower limit is similar (remember that the result of integration is the indefinite integral, evaluated at both limits, with a minus between them). So in general, you have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$$
If $f$ also depends on x, you have another term that involves derivative under the integral sign.